# Display View in twig

Tags: drupal, twig

I created (in Drupal 8) a view of a dataset (newsteaser_mit_bild) with some News in there.
With this view i created a block. The name is automatically generated (views_block__newsteaser_mit_bild_block_1).

The normal content is displayed with

```
{{ page.content }}
```

How can i display this View in my Twig File ?

```
{{ page.newsteaser_mit_bild }}
```

seems not to be right.

How can i use the view/block in my twig an how can i template them ?

Answer (score 3):

In the main twig file you can use name block like this:

```
{% block my_custom_block }%

{% endblock my_custom_block %}
```

In the another twig file you can call the block like this:

```
{% extends 'link_for_file.twig' %}
{% block my_custom_block }%
{{ parent() }}
{% endblock  my_custom_block }%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess a new variable and use views_embed_view like:

```
function THEME-NAME_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['MY-VIEW-NAME'] = views_embed_view('VIEW-ID');
}
```

And then in the twig file:

```
{{ MY-VIEW-NAME }}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.
This is in my dumdumtheme.theme file:
function dumdumtheme_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['standout_link_home_view'] = views_embed_view('block_1');
}

This is in page.html.twig:
{{ standout_link_home_view }}

But the content doesn't display.
The  $variables
is from  Structure / Views list, "machine name" column; and the :
views_embed_view('block_1');
is from  Advanced /Other / Machine Name: in the Editor for this view.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you elaborate on that for me?